# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Why am I getting the following error in my code?

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in....

I I had return statements inside the if...else when i first started working on this function, and the error seems like one that has to do with return statements. but i replaced them with echo statement's and I'm still getting the error's so I have no clue what's going on. Any help or advise?

```
public function wallPostComments() {
    // This function processes wall post comments
    // pull the submitted comment data
    $returnedPostId = $this->inuput->post('entryId');
    $returnedCommentData = $this->input->post('returnedCommentData');

    // pull the required session data
    $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');

    // select the sql data from wallPosts and wallPostComments
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM wallPosts, wallPostComments");

    // loop through the mysql rows and process the expanded sql code
    foreach ($query->result() as row()) {
        if($row->idwallPosts == $JSONedIdWallPosts) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "failure";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using `wallPostComments()`? Show that code.  Where is `$JSONedIdWallPosts` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When did `row()` become a function?

Try:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
```

Comment: Ahhh everyone has THOSE days, don't feel bad.